# Adding a modal after adding to cart

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping, modal

What would be the best way to create a modal after adding a product to cart (Showing "continue shopping" or "checkout")?

I though about using just JS with event. But, I don't know how to concile this the AJAX result.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can show ajax popup by extending `catalog-add-to-cart.js` file of Magento-Catalog module.

Steps to do :

1 - Copy **catalog-add-to-cart.js** from '\module-catalog\view\frontend\web\js/catalog-add-to-cart.js and place into your theme folder \Package/theme/Magento_Catalog/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js

2 - find **ajaxSubmit:** function and place below code snippet after **self.enableAddToCartButton(form);**

Code snippet :

```
//popup code start
                var popup = $('<div class="add-to-cart-dialog"/>').html($('.page-title span').text() + '<span> has been added to cart.</span>').modal({ //get product name from product view page only
                    modalClass: 'add-to-cart-popup',
                    //title: $.mage.__("No Title"),
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            text: 'Continue Shopping',
                            click: function () {
                                this.closeModal();
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Proceed to Checkout',
                            click: function () {
                                window.location = window.checkout.checkoutUrl
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                });
                popup.modal('openModal');
                //popup code end
```

And you are done. deploy-statcic content, flush cache etc

Comment: Your answer is almost the same than this one : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150794/i-want-to-add-popup-notify-after-adding-products-magento-2
But yours is easier to implement and is perfectly working. Big thanks !

Comment: Thanks you got the my answer.. now i am trying to override JS

Comment: @SatishVishwakarma, good happy to know if that works for you too, happy coding.

Comment: @NaveedAsim, How can we use modal pop up if product is added to cart from custom page from ajax request by passing product id.

Comment: Hello @NaveedAsim, this override work on Magento 2.3.3 ? On you're customisation, if i want to show picture of product and the price, how i can do it ? should I override controller of module-catalog ?

Comment: @devmagento, yes this also work on Magento 2.3.3. However you should be able to get the price and image path using their respective tag class or id.

Comment: Thanks , it works perfect , just as i wanted , :)

Comment: it will not show the product name on category page , so keep that thing in mind while implementing this

Comment: The solution was working fine, but only for the category and product pages. But not working for the homepage Add to cart button from the mageplaza product sliders.