# How to add "Add To Cart" Pop Up Magento 2 Custom theme?

Tags: magento2, addtocart, modal-popup

> Here i am trying to add a pop-up once product added to cart using
>   custom theme magento 2??

I tried this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150794/i-want-to-add-popup-notify-after-adding-products-magento-2)

Comment: not very related to your issue, but popups/modals are not good UI element for this matter. I mean there was a reason behind it that magento doesn't have popup when you add an item to your basket. May be you should rethink about this design element that you want to add.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to add popup notify after adding products Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150794/i-want-to-add-popup-notify-after-adding-products-magento-2)