# Magento2: How to use checkbox in model popup in js?

Tags: magento2, javascript

I have created a model popup, that will appear when user click on add to cart. Now I want to add check box to accept user acceptance by click on checkbox.

Can someone please help to to do this .

Comment: Show your code here.

Comment: I am using [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150794/i-want-to-add-popup-notify-after-adding-products-magento-2) answer to add popup